# Inverse bounded in a Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A: X \rightarrow X $ be a bounded linear operator such that $A'(\tilde{X})=\tilde{X}$, show that $A$ has a bounded inverse (on its range).

If someone could proof that the range of $A$ is closed it end the problem, because after that we can just apply the open map theorem.

PS. $A'$ is the adjoint of $A$ and $\tilde{X}$ is the topological dual of $X$. This problem is from Bachman book's Functional Analysis.

Comment: Do you know the closed graph theorem? Then, your assumption implies that $A$ is injective and has a closed range. Then, your assertion follows by another famous theorem.

Comment: I know that $A$ is one to ano, but why the range is closed?

Comment: This follows, e.g., by the closed range theorem. Maybe you can consider $A : X \to cl(range(A))$ and obtain that the adjoint of this operator is invertible.

Comment: I don no know the range closed theorem, can you say me a book or place to read this theorem? thank you so much.

Comment: It should be contained in (almost) any book on functional analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the closure of the range of $A$. We define
$B : X \to Y$ by $B x = A x$ for all $x \in X$.

Let us show that $B' : \tilde Y \to \tilde X$ is invertible. Since the range of $B$ is dense, $B'$ is injective. It remains to show that $B$ is surjective. For any $\tilde x \in \tilde X$, there is $\tilde r \in \tilde X$, such that $A'\tilde r = \tilde x$. Now, let $\tilde y \in Y'$ be the restriction of $\tilde r$ to $Y$. Then,
$$
\langle \tilde x, x\rangle =
\langle A' \tilde r, x\rangle =
\langle \tilde r, Ax\rangle =
\langle \tilde y, Bx\rangle =
\langle B'\tilde y, x\rangle
$$ for all $x \in X$. Hence, $B'\tilde y  =\tilde x$ and $B'$ is surjective.

This shows that $B'$ is boundedly invertible by the open mapping theorem. Moreover, the bounded invertibility of $B$ follows.